# JS Revealing Module Pattern scope / references

Tags: javascript, reference, leaflet, mapbox

I think I am misunderstanding scope or references in JS a little bit.

I'm using Leaflet to initiate a new map object. My code is something like this:

```
var revealing = (function() {
    var mapEl = "#map";
    var mapName = "map";
    var mapboxMap = '----';
    var map;


    var init = function() {
        map = L.mapbox.map(mapName, mapboxMap);
        map.setView([40, -100], 5);
    }

    return {
        "init": init
    }

}());
```

If I reference 'map' inside the init function, I get what I want. But anywhere else that I reference map (either within the function or elsewhere via the 'revealing' object, I get a reference to the html object that leafleft (L.mapbox...) has created, rather than the instantiated object I get inside init().

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown the code where you're having trouble (e.g., accessing `map` and not getting what you expect), but I suspect the problem isn't scope, it's *timing*.

Anywhere within your big anonymous function, `map` will resolve to the `map` variable you've declared within that function. But that variable has the value `undefined` until `init` sets it to something. At that point, it has the value that `init` assigns to it.

More in this example:

```
var revealing = (function() {
    var mapEl = "#map";
    var mapName = "map";
    var mapboxMap = '----';
    var map;


    var init = function() {
        map = L.mapbox.map(mapName, mapboxMap);
        map.setView([40, -100], 5);
    }

    var useMap = function() {
        console.log(map); // <============== 1 - See 3 and 4 below
    };

    console.log(map);     // <============== 2 - Shows "undefined"

    return {
        "init": init,
        "useMap": useMap
    }

}());
revealing.useMap();       // <============== 3 - Shows "undefined"
revealing.init();
revealing.useMap();       // <============== 4 - Shows the map created in `init`
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have provided more context. I believe my issue was actually a leaflet issue. Accepting your answer because I failed to ask the correct question and your response addresses what I actually asked.

Comment: @user3522562: LOL! :-)